# Images caching size

Tags: image, product-images

I've uploaded 3 images in admin thumbnail, small image and base image. None of the images I've uploaded is 400x400.
images [here](http://www.timports.co.uk/kiln-dried-logs) in the grid

I need the small-image to be cached at 155x155

Why are my images being cached at 400x400 ?

How can I stop the cache setting to 400x400 ?

It slows down my page speed so much, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the **admin panel -> System -> Configuration -> ADVANCED -> Developer -> Debug -> Template Path Hints** and select **Yes** (before this you have to change **Current Configuration Scope** to your website). Don't forget to fill in your IP in **Developer Client Restrictions**. After this refresh your cache. Then open your product list and see which template is used (most probably it's something like this: **template/catalog/product/list.phtml**). In this file search for `resize` (most probably it will be `resize(400)`) and change it to `resize(155)`.

Answer (score 0):

i tried the template path hints but no path given, [image: no template path]

I found this

```
<?php // Product Image ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(155); ?>" width="155" height="155" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
```

as you can see the image is already set to resize 155

any other ideas would be much appreicated.